# Agregar multiples imágenes al mismo tiempo en Laravel

Tags: html5, laravel, laravel-blade

Me encontré con un problema en Laravel, estoy tratando de agregar varias imagenes al mismo tiempo utilizando el atributo multiple en un input de tipo file:

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" multiple class="form-control">
```

Si por ejemplo selecciono 3 imagenes y le doy a enviar, luego le doy return en el metodo store:

```
return $files = $request->file('image');
```

me muestra de la siguiente manera:

```
[
  {},
  {},
  {}
]
```

y al acceder a alguna de las propiedades de ese objeto me retorna(varia según la posición a la que acceda):

```
D:\xampp\tmp\php698A.tmp
```

Luego convierto a una ruta válida con:

```
$upload->upload_global($files[0], 'productimage');
```

Y me retorna:

```
/uploads/productimage/1552657379_1552657379.jpg
```

Hasta ahí todo correcto, lo que quisiera saber es como registrar todas las imágenes. He utilizado for y foreach y ninguno me resulta, solo guarda la primera imagen:

for:

```
        $files = $request->file('image');

        for ($i=0; $i < count($files) ; $i++) {
            $this->modelo::create([
                'title' => $request->title,
                'product_id' => base64_decode($request->product_id),
                'image' => $upload->upload_global($file, 'productimage'),
                'create_uid' => Auth::user()->id,
                'write_uid' => Auth::user()->id
            ]);
        }
```

foreach:

```
        $files = $request->file('image');

        foreach($files as $file){
            $this->modelo::create([
                'title' => $request->title,
                'product_id' => base64_decode($request->product_id),
                'image' => $upload->upload_global($file, 'productimage'),
                'create_uid' => Auth::user()->id,
                'write_uid' => Auth::user()->id
            ]);
        }
```

Y en los 2 casos me guarda solo la primera imagen. Eso quiere decir que no recorre la $i, pero siempre me sube la misma imagen repetidas veces según la cantidad de imágenes que seleccione. ¿Cómo podría hacer que me suban todas las imágenes? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: `$this->model->save();` luego de `$this->modelo::create`

Comment: No funciona, continúa con los mismo.

Comment: puedes hacer un dd de tu `dd($request->file('image'));` y agregarlo a tu pregunta?

Comment: array:3 [▼
  0 => UploadedFile {#1189 ▶}
  1 => UploadedFile {#1190 ▶}
  2 => UploadedFile {#1191 ▶}
]

Comment: dale un `$request->file('image')[0]` o en el for `$request->file('image')[$i]`

Comment: Lastimosamente tampoco resultó

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91082/discussion-between-bryro-and-marianoc1993).

Comment: puedes hacer  checkar que `$upload->upload_global($file, 'productimage')` no te esté devolviendo el mismo nombre de imagen y se estén pisando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**debes hacerlo asi:**

```
    $files = $request->file('image');

    foreach($files as $file){
        $this->modelo::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'product_id' => base64_decode($request->product_id),
            'image' => $upload->upload_global($file, 'productimage'),
            'create_uid' => Auth::user()->id,
            'write_uid' => Auth::user()->id
        ]);
    }

function upload_global($file, $folder){ 

    $file_type = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    $folder = $folder; 
    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/uploads/'.$folder; 
    $destinationPathThumb = public_path() . '/uploads/'.$folder.'thumb'; 
    $filename = uniqid().'_'.time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $url = '/uploads/'.$folder.'/'.$filename; 

    if ($file->move($destinationPath.'/' , $filename)) { 
        return $filename; 
    } 
}
```